# Cancel Debounce Function

Tags: javascript

I have the following debounce function and I need to be able to cancel the debounce by calling `clearTimeout(timeout);` within the scope of the `debounce` function. I cannot use a library for this.

Here is my code:

```
var utils = (function(){
    return {
        debounce: function(func, wait, immediate){
          var timeout;
            return function() {
                var context = this, args = arguments;
                var later = function() {
                    timeout = null;
                    if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
                };
                var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
                if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
            };
        }
    }
})();
```

I want to be able to do something like this but again I cannot figure it out.

```
var deb = utils.debounce(function(){ console.log("do something"); }, 500);

$(document).on('keyup', '#myId', deb);

deb.cancel(); //this cancel call clears the timeout variable in the debounce function.
```

Comment: Declare `timeout` in the outer scope (just before `return`), and create `cancel` method to the object.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but I'm wondering why you declared a function that returns an object. Why not just create an object?

Comment: I did try that and it worked but it only allows for one invocation of debounce. I have a few different places where it is used and I would like to cancel an individual call rather than globally. @Teemu

Comment: The reason was when I first coded all of this it was very simple and I just needed a few utils methods that were namespaced. This pattern allowed me to make private functions rather than exposing everything through an object. @IanGuimarães

Comment: Was the calling example purposed to actually work? I don't mean the cancel part, but `utils.debounce(...)`.

Comment: Yes, it works as expected. @Teemu

Comment: ?? I can't get it work in a fiddle. added `()` at the end of the IIFE, so that `utils` actually gets defined with an object.

Comment: You're correct. I accidentally left that out. @Teemu

Comment: Yes, but I added it, and then running the example never fires the console.log.

Comment: @Teemu I added the listener I am using to the question that invokes debounce. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the cancel function as a property to the returned function:

```
const utils = (function(){
  return {
    debounce: function(func, wait, immediate) {
      let timeout;
      const fn = function() {
        const context = this, args = arguments;
        const later = function() {
          timeout = null;
          if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        const callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
      };
      return Object.assign(fn, {
        clear() { clearTimeout(timeout); }
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What goes in place of the comments?

Comment: @CannonMoyer I edited the answer to fit the example you provided. JonasWilms Hope that that's what you meant.